# calculation of wall clock

Tags: c, clock

How to modify this code to do sequential
program to calculate the wall clock time
(time_t) needed to calculate the dot product
of the complex numbers.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct complex{
double real;
double img;
}complex;

complex add(complex a, complex b);
complex multiply(complex *a, complex *b);


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int choice, temp1, temp2;
complex a, b, c;

while (1)
{
    printf("Press 1 to add two complex numbers.\n");
    printf("Press 2 to multiply two complex numbers.\n");
    printf("Press 3 to exit.\n");
    printf("Enter your choice\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);

    if (choice == 3)
        exit(0);

    if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 2)
    {
        printf("Enter a and b where a + ib is the first complex number.");
        printf("\na = ");
        scanf_s("%d", &a.real);
        printf("b = ");
        scanf_s("%d", &a.img);
        printf("Enter c and d where c + id is the second complex number.");
        printf("\nc = ");
        scanf_s("%d", &b.real);
        printf("d = ");
        scanf_s("%d", &b.img);
    }
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        c.real = a.real + b.real;
        c.img = a.img + b.img;

        if (c.img >= 0)
        printf("Sum of two complex numbers = %d + %di", c.real, c.img);
        else
        printf("Sum of two complex numbers = %d %di", c.real, c.img);
    }

    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        c.real = a.real*b.real - a.img*b.img;
        c.img = a.img*b.real + a.real*b.img;

    if (c.img >= 0)
    printf("Multiplication of two complex numbers = %d + %di", c.real, c.img);
        else
    printf("Multiplication of two complex numbers = %d %di", c.real, c.img);
    }


    else
    printf("Invalid choice.");

    printf("\nPress any key to enter choice again...\n");
}
    }
```

Comment: Benchmarking is tricky. Complex arithmetic is not so tricky that you will be able to measure how long it takes with `time_t`, which has a granularity of one second on most systems.  You will have to repeat the calculation a few million times to get it to take long enough to be measurable, and you'll probably need to use a better measure than `time()` and `time_t`.  At minimum, use `clock()`.  More likely use `gettimeofday()` which reports to microseconds, or `clock_gettime()` which reports to nanoseconds.  Which platform are you on?  The answer is different for Windows.

Comment: Note that if the optimizer spots you not using the results of the calculation, it may optimize the calculation out of the code, so you will see things running very fast.  Outsmarting the optimizer without completely inhibiting it either is one of the things that makes benchmarking hard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You [shouldn't use `gettimeofday`](http://blog.eitanadler.com/2012/11/dont-use-gettimeofday2-or-time3-for.html) either (there should be another link with more helpful alternatives, but I can't find it right now).

Comment: @Kninnug: [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) has some caveats -- such as it can be screwed up if SNTP or NTP (or a system administrator) adjust the clock while you're benchmarking, and it is marked obsolescent by POSIX 2008 (you're supposed to use [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) with CLOCK_MONOTONIC).  However, `gettimeofday()` still has some things going for it, such as "it exists on Mac OS X and `clock_gettime()` does not". _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ If you're publishing your benchmarks and your system has `clock_gettime()`, you should use it. If you're not publishing your benchmarks or your system doesn't have `clock_gettime()`, then `gettimeofday()` is a lot better than [`time()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html) or [`clock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html). Yes, you have to be careful interpreting the results, but it gives you roughly the right figures most of the time. It is usually good enough when there isn't a better alternative.

Comment: _[...continuation of the continuation...]_ And if you're worried about the system overhead, by all means get involved in the intricacies of [`getrusage()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrusage.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical approach is to record `time()` twice and run the code many times to get a 1st order approximation.

```
time_t t0,t1;
time(&t0);
int N = 1000000;
for (int i=0; i< N; i++) {
  DoCodeUnderTest();
  // c.real = a.real + b.real;
  // c.img = a.img + b.img;
}
time(&t1);
printf("Time %e\n", (double) (t1-t0) / N);
```

Suggest using profiling tools for a more accurate answer.

---

@Jonathan Leffler suggestion to use `clock()` is also an improvement.

```
clock_t c1,c12;
c1 = clock();
...  // repeat runs of the code
c2 = clock();
printf("Time %e\n", (double) (c1-c0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / N);
```

Given 1) @Jonathan Leffler 2nd suggestion about the legitimacy of repeating since a compiler may out-think the code and 2) cache issues hints that any brute force methods as suggested here are at best illustrative and not definitive time measurements.